# Does every static factory methods internally uses new keyword to create object?

Tags: java, methods, static

I checked with following commonly used static factory methods and each one of them internally uses new keyword to create object

1. `valueOf()`

   ```
    public static String More ...valueOf(char c) {
        char data[] = {c};
        return new String(data, true);
    }

    public static String More ...valueOf(int i) {
        return Integer.toString(i);
    }
   ```
2. `toString()` returns `return new String(buf, true);`

   Source: `java.lang.String.java`

Part two of relevant source: `getInstance()`

```
public static Calendar More ...getInstance()
{
    Calendar cal = createCalendar(TimeZone.getDefaultRef(), 
    Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT));
    cal.sharedZone = true;
    return cal;
}
```

`createCalendar` method internally creates `Calendar` object using `new` keyword.

Source: `java.util.Calendar.java`

Is there any static factory method, which internally do not create object using `new` keyword?

Comment: `Long.valueOf` sometimes uses pre-created objects from pool

Comment: The only way to create a new object is to use `new` (or reflection).  However, a factory might not itself create the object, but use a cache or pre-created object.

Comment: Static and new are not related in functionality, so most likely they do exist or you can create them yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that (in Java) the only way to create objects is `new`.

Somewhere down the line factory methods must be returning objects that were constructed with `new`.

There are some global objects like `System.out` that could (in principle) be instantiated by the run-time environment some other way.

That doesn't mean factory methods call `new` one-for-one with calls to them.
For example `Integer.valueof(int v)` is required to cache values at least in the range [-128,127]. 
So before or during the first call of `Integer.valueof(0)` `new` should be called (or in effect called) but subsequent calls will return the cached object.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)

Answer (score 1):

You have 3  ways :

1) A factory whose the types to instantiate are known at compile time use the `new` operator. 
It is the best way as it is straight and the compiler enforces also the validity of the object creation.

2) In some particular cases, the types to instantiate may not be known at compile time.
In this case, the reflection is unavoidable.
It relies on `Class.forName()` to retrieve the class and `Class.newInstance()` method to instantiate the class.

Look for example the `java.net.InetAddress` class.
It has a `loadImpl()` factory method that works in this way.
You can see that `Class.forName()` and `Class.newInstance()` are methods that may throw "technical" exceptions and these will be discovered only at runtime.

```
static InetAddressImpl loadImpl(String implName) {
    Object impl = null;

    /*
     * Property "impl.prefix" will be prepended to the classname
     * of the implementation object we instantiate, to which we
     * delegate the real work (like native methods).  This
     * property can vary across implementations of the java.
     * classes.  The default is an empty String "".
     */
    String prefix = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                  new GetPropertyAction("impl.prefix", ""));
    try {
        impl = Class.forName("java.net." + prefix + implName).newInstance();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Class not found: java.net." + prefix +
                           implName + ":\ncheck impl.prefix property " +
                           "in your properties file.");
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not instantiate: java.net." + prefix +
                           implName + ":\ncheck impl.prefix property " +
                           "in your properties file.");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot access class: java.net." + prefix +
                           implName + ":\ncheck impl.prefix property " +
                           "in your properties file.");
    }

    if (impl == null) {
        try {
            impl = Class.forName(implName).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error("System property impl.prefix incorrect");
        }
    }

    return (InetAddressImpl) impl;
}
```

3) Sometimes, the created object with `new` or `newInstance()` may be cached to avoid creating multiple times the same object.
It may make sense for immutable objects.